# Python Stale Element Reference: Element not attached to page document

Tags: python, selenium

having trouble getting around Stale Element reference. I think the innerArticles array is at fault, as it is controlling the whole for loop. After I refresh explicitly i get stale element exception.

Esentially I want the page to keep refreshing until the 'Text' in SubItems xpath has appeared on the page. As I do not know when this will occur I need to start and keep reloading.

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
innerArticles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']")

for links in innerArticles:
    print('inFor')

    SubItems = links.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='Text']")

    iterator = 0
    if len(SubItems) < 1:
        print('Sub < 1')
        while iterator < 5:
            print('While', iterator)

            time.sleep(1)  # sleep 1 seconds to refresh again
            iterator = iterator + 1  # iterate
            driver.refresh()  # refresh
            SubItems = links.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='Text']")
            break
            if len(SubItems) > 0:
                print('break')
                break

    if len(SubItems) > 0:
        print('SecondIf')
        if links.text.startswith('SText') and links.text.endswith('SText'):
            links.click()
```

Comment: is it certain that once the page is loaded, the text will be there? or the text appearance is purely random and uncertain?

Comment: Yes, it is nearly as certain as can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing the explicit refresh, the links object will not longer be valid and will throw the `StaleElementReferenceException`. You should get that element again after the refresh. You can try something like below:

```
innerArticles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']")

for i in range(len(innerArticles)):
    print('inFor')

    SubItems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']")[i].find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='Text']")

    iterator = 0
    if len(SubItems) < 1:
        print('Sub < 1')
        while iterator < 5:
            print('While', iterator)

            time.sleep(1)  # sleep 1 seconds to refresh again
            iterator = iterator + 1  # iterate
            driver.refresh()  # refresh
            SubItems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']")[i].find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='Text']")
            break
            if len(SubItems) > 0:
                print('break')
                break

    if len(SubItems) > 0:
        print('SecondIf')
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']")[i]
        if links.text.startswith('SText') and links.text.endswith('SText'):
            links.click()
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Very much appreciated, have been at this for few days :) Am brand new to Python and Selenium but I see you are rebuilding post refresh with concat methodology ?

Comment: @gamb1t_88 - I just tried to work with your existing code. Welcome to python & selenium. Research more on how you can approach the same thing in a better way. Why do you need to refresh the page?

Comment: Essentially do not know when the page will have data I need, not due to load time rather when the data posts to page. Is there a smarter solution ?

Comment: Can't really say without looking at the page itself. May be you can try wait for some element to be displayed. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: I did have this implemented and it worked, but to me it seems that explicit wait as you mention will only wait for elements to render that are in a cache, rather than new updated data to the page itself? I was uncertain of using the approach.

Comment: wait is applicable for new elements to appear on the page. You can carry on with the current implementation if it meets your needs